# Removing unused lproj languages from xCode build at build time?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been searching for a script  that will remove unwanted languages from a project at build time... With out getting into great detail. I have a project which has subprojects, some of these subprojects have localizations which I do not want to ship with (since apple looks at the lproj folders to state what languages you support).

What I would like is a script that I can run and tell it to only have x languages or remove x languages and then build...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If your unwanted localizations come from CocoaPods in use, install this CocoaPods plugin:

https://github.com/dtorres/cocoapods-prune-localizations

Worked like a charm for me.

Otherwise, you might be able to extract code from this plugin to accomplish your task.